# google sheet : function convert number (string) into money format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When i put number in a cell, i can use numbering/money format. For example :

```
123456 into 123,456.00
```

but this time , i need something like this but using function. Because the number will be add to a string. For example :

```
= "USD "& A1
```

if A1 contains 123456 then the output will be :

```
USD 123456
```

But i want the output to be formatted like this :

```
USD 123,456.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
= "USD "& text(A1, "#000,000.00")
```

and see if that helps?